# how to sum up total from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program with related to taking orders in a shop. The entire code is about the page where an order is taken and then a list of labels is created. All is done well however I'm not able to get the total of the prices. Here is my code :

```
def blnclick():
    n=0
    uprice = price.get()
    uitem = item.get()
    order = {'items': uitem, 'price': uprice}
    lab = order['items']
    lab1 = order['price']
    total = int(lab1)
    c = Canvas(canvas_frme, bg='white', bd=10, width=10, height=50)
    c.pack()
    for values in order:
        Label(c, text=lab, bg='white', font=('candara', 19)).grid(row=n, column=0)
        Label(c, text=lab1, bg='white', font=('candara', 19)).grid(row=n, column=1)
        totSum.set(total)
        total = total+total
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

**update:** I think that the code is not good at handling the dictionary because every time I'm trying a new code to total up the prices it always sums up the didgits that are entered once and resets after new entry is inserted. anything. 
please note that i'm a still a learner/ student of python, so any working changes in the code would be acceptable.

**update#2**  when you guys go for shopping you buy multiple items and then the list of items come out with the total amount. i'm trying to do exactly that. feel free to change the code according to your needs as i am a learner and i commit mistakes a lot of times. thanks all

Comment: you should have class variable to keep total - ie. `self.total.value`. Now you create local variable `total` which can't keep older value. Besides you assign new value to total `total = int(lab1)` so it removes olvder value.

Comment: to add widget to canvas you would have to use `canvas_window((x,y), widget). We use `pack()/grid()` to add widgets to other widget - like Frame. Now you have some mess.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a list comprehension to get all the numbers in a list and the sum them

```
# sample dict 
d = {"one":1, "two":2, "three":3}

# for each key, get it's "price", sum list
x = sum([d[k] for k in d])
```

Comment: I don't think that it would work because the dictionary would not save all the values I enter it will only create the label of that entry. I think the previous entry is deleted when I insert a new one therefore, sum from the list won't be usefull (according to my guess!)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - do you mean if there is an order containing more than one of the same thing it doesn't work? ie, if you had a {"Jacket": 40, "Jacket": 45}?

Comment: i'm trying here is creating multiple values. for example: when you go to a shop and buy more than one items, and then the list of items is created, i'm trying to do that here exactly, i'm trying to create a list of multiple items, in specific terms, in key item : price, i have to store orders like: 'shirts:$30', 'jackets:$50', 'tshirts:$25', etc.

Comment: I see. It looks like you will need to have a dict of items of each category, get the total the same way I showed you, and then add them up.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple to do with `sum`:

```
total = sum(int(value) for key, value in order.items())
```

Comment: it shows an error : " unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' "

Comment: @AndriousPrime Check my edited answer. Your prices just were strings, so need to cast them first.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you create local variable `total` which can't keep older value.
Besides you assign new value `total = int(lab1)` so it removes older value.

You need global variable (`global total`) to keep total value all time.
And then you can add new value to `total` which keeps older value.

To add widget to canvas you would have to use `canvas_window((x,y), widget)`.
We use `pack()`/`grid()` to add widgets to other widget like `Frame`. Now you have some mess.

I use `Frame` and I skip not important options like color and font.

```
#global variable 
total = 0 # value as start

# to keep all orderde items
#order = []

# to display total value 
#total_label = Label(root, text='')
#total_label.pack()

def blnclick():

    uprice = price.get()
    uitem = item.get()

    global total
    total += int(uprice) # add to global value

    # display new total
    #total_label['text'] = str(total)

    # add ordered item to list
    #order.append({'item': uitem, 'price': uprice})

    frame = Frame(canvas_frme)
    frame.pack()

    l = Label(frame, text=uprice)
    l.grid(row=0, column=0)

    l = Label(frame, text=uitem)
    l.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working example

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_button_add():

    uprice = price_entry.get()
    uitem = item_entry.get()

    global total
    total += int(uprice) # add to class value

    # display new total
    total_label['text'] = str(total)

    # add ordered item to list
    order.append({'item': uitem, 'price': uprice})
    print('full order:', order)
    print('total:', total)

    number = len(order)

    l = tk.Label(frame_order, text=uitem)
    l.grid(row=number, column=0)

    l = tk.Label(frame_order, text=uprice)
    l.grid(row=number, column=1)

# --- main ---

# values at start
total = 0
order = []

root = tk.Tk()

#--- entry for new item ---

l = tk.Label(root, text='Item:')
l.grid(row=0, column=0)

item_entry = tk.Entry(root)
item_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

l = tk.Label(root, text='Price:')
l.grid(row=1, column=0)

price_entry = tk.Entry(root)
price_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text='ADD', command=on_button_add)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

#--- frame with order ---

frame_order = tk.Frame(root)
frame_order.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

l = tk.Label(frame_order, text="Items")
l.grid(row=0, column=0)

l = tk.Label(frame_order, text="Prices")
l.grid(row=0, column=1)

#--- total ---

# to display total value 
l = tk.Label(root, text='Total:')
l.grid(row=4, column=0)

# to display total value 
total_label = tk.Label(root, text='')
total_label.grid(row=4, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: this code works fine as per my requirement. thank you!